# C++ function pointer return type

Tags: c++, function, templates, callback, function-pointers

Given is the following class (just the header):

```
class Example {

public:

    template<class C>
    Example(bool(C::*callbackFunc)(Foo&) = nullptr) : callbackFunc(callbackFunc);

    template<class C>
    ??? getCallbackFunc() const {
        return callbackFunc;
    }

private:

    // store the func ptr
    template<class C>
    bool (C::*callbackFunc)(Foo&);
};
```

What is the correct return type of the getter `getCallbackFunc()`?

Comment: `Example::callbackFunc` is a function declaration, not a variable. Look up most vexing parse.

Comment: Can you really store a member template?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is:

```
bool(C::*)(Foo&)
```

However, this won't help you much, as you cannot store a template variable in a class instance:

```
template<class C>
bool (C::*callbackFunc)(Foo&);
```

That is not a legal variable declaration, and you really cannot fix it.

Replace `callbackFunc` with

```
std::function< bool(void*, Foo&) > callbackFunc;
```

Then in `Example` ctor write a function that converts the member ptr into such a function.  It involves a static cast from`void*` to `C*`.

Get callback func returns:

```
std::function< bool(C*, Foo&) >
```

which is implicitly-converible-to from `callbackFunc`.

You use it by passing `C*` in and the `Foo&`.

Comment: Can you show how the ctor of ``Example`` must look like? I still don't get it to work. :( ``C*`` is not known when getCallbackFunc() is called.

Comment: @user `<C>` has to be passed in as written.  Odds are you have an XY problem where you asked for a solution to X but your real problem is Y.   `: callbackFunc([callbackFunc](void*ptr, Foo&foo)->bool{ return (static_cast<C*>(ptr)->*callbackFunc)(foo); }){}` or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is you can't have templated member variables without temlating the entire class. Once that's fixed we can try to figure out the return value of your `getCallbackFunc` function using [The Right Left Rule](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations#right_left_rule). I added a body to your constructor because you provided an init-list (inline constructor).

```
struct Foo {};

// need to template the whole class to
// template member variables
template<class C>
class Example {

public:

    Example(bool(C::*callbackFunc)(Foo&) = nullptr)
    : callbackFunc(callbackFunc) {} // init list means this needs a body

    // use the right-left-rule 
    bool (C::*getCallbackFunc())(Foo&) {
        return callbackFunc;
    }

private:

    // store the func ptr
    bool (C::*callbackFunc)(Foo&);
};

class CallbackClass
{
public:
    bool call_me_back(Foo&) { std::cout << "Glad you called" << '\n'; return true; }
};

int main()
{
    Example<CallbackClass> eg(&CallbackClass::call_me_back);

    CallbackClass cbc; // instantiate something to call

    Foo foo; // need a foo for parameter

    // get fn pointer, dereference it and call it with cbc object
    bool return_value = (cbc.*eg.getCallbackFunc())(foo);
}
```

This can all be simplified somewhat using the `using` declaration to create a *type alias*:

```
struct Foo {};

// create a templated type alias
template<typename C>
using CallbackType = bool(C::*)(Foo&);

// need to template the whole class to
// template member variables
template<class C>
class Example {

public:

    Example(CallbackType<C> callbackFunc = nullptr)
    : callbackFunc(callbackFunc) {} // init list means this needs a body

    // using the type alias
    CallbackType<C> getCallbackFunc() {
        return callbackFunc;
    }

private:

    // store the func ptr
    CallbackType<C> callbackFunc;
};

class CallbackClass
{
public:
    bool call_me_back(Foo&) { std::cout << "Glad you called" << '\n'; return true; }
};

int main()
{
    Example<CallbackClass> eg(&CallbackClass::call_me_back);

    CallbackClass cbc; // instantiate something to call

    Foo foo; // need a foo for parameter

    // get fn pointer
    CallbackType<CallbackClass> cb = eg.getCallbackFunc();

    // dereference it and call it with cbc object
    bool return_value = (cbc.*cb)(foo);
}
```